# jQuery counting function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this to launch a counting function when I reach #counter. when I scroll to #counter the number go from 1 to 600 like it suppose to. the problem is that it goes back to 1. I just wanted to stay at 600.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var hT = $('#counter').offset().top,
    hH = $('#counter').outerHeight(),
    wH = $(window).height(),
    wS = $(this).scrollTop();
  console.log((hT - wH), wS);

  if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {
    $('.count').each(function() {
      $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
      }, {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function(now) {
          $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
      });
    });
  }

});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 900px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div id="counter">
  <div><span class="count">600</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML as well.

Comment: ok ! I just did !

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing a console.log thrown into the step method to see how many animates are being run concurrently.

Comment: the console is full of stuff like this 32 600
custom.js:880 32 598
custom.js:880 32 590
custom.js:880 32 564
custom.js:880 32 523

Answer (score 0):

You could just stop the animation once the value is 600 using `.stop()` jQuery method.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var hT = $('#counter').offset().top,
   hH = $('#counter').outerHeight(),
   wH = $(window).height(),
   wS = $(this).scrollTop();

if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)) {
 
$('.count').each(function (index, value) {
    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
 }, {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
   if(Math.ceil(now) === 600){
    $(this).stop(true, true);
   }
        }
    });
    });
}

});
```

```css
#counter{
 margin-top: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Counter</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>scroll to view the counter</p>
<div id="counter">
<div><span class="count">600</span></div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a jsbin of the above snippet https://jsbin.com/dejeji/edit?html,js,output